# How should I host images used on Tumblr?

Tags: images, tumblr

I would like to add some images into my Tumblr post (which is made up of text), unfortunately it is only possible to embed images by URL.

Is it a good idea to upload the images first (as a photo), mark them as private and then use them when I post a message?

I tested and it works, but I am wondering if it is a feature or a bug and it will be impossible when Tumblr fixes it.

Is there another better way maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images in deleted posts, either uploaded as part of a photo post or inline, are not deleted if the post is. It is most definitely **not** a bug because otherwise when a post is deleted, there would be tons of problems with reblogs. Only access to the post is restricted (how would people find the images anyway? Have you look at their urls?).

However, there is already a method to upload inline pictures:

[image]

See that discreet link in the corner above the post area? You can use it to upload images.

Comment: Thanks Circeus, I have no idea why I never noticed this option before. 
Urls I checked usually used some external hosting.

Comment: @mrok I'll guess many people don't notice it either! Also Tumblr has a terrible handling of big gif files, which may be a factor.